# Normal ordering for a two fermion case

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, anticommutator

I am trying to understand how normal ordering works. I am considering a system of two photons, with $\hat{f}_i$ and $\hat{f}_i^\dagger$ being the annihilation and creation operators, respectively. I am trying to find the following

$$:\hat{f}_2\hat{f}_1^\dagger\hat{f}_2^\dagger:$$

Using the anticommutation relations,

$$\hat{f}_2\hat{f}_1^\dagger\hat{f}_2^\dagger=-\hat{f}_1^\dagger\hat{f}_2\hat{f}_2^\dagger=\hat{f}_1^\dagger(1-\hat{f}_2^\dagger\hat{f}_2)$$

because $\hat{f}_i\hat{f}_j^\dagger=\delta_{ij}-\hat{f}_j^\dagger\hat{f}_i$, which doesn't match the answer in the [relevant Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_order#Examples_4).

The answer listed on Wikipedia is $:\hat{f}_2\hat{f}_1^\dagger\hat{f}_2^\dagger:=\hat{f}_1^\dagger\hat{f}_2^\dagger\hat{f}_2=-\hat{f}_2^\dagger\hat{f}_1^\dagger\hat{f}_2$.

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding $:\hat{f}_2\hat{f}_1^\dagger\hat{f}_2^\dagger:$ is defined to be equal to $\hat{f}_1^\dagger\hat{f}_2^\dagger\hat{f}_2$. Otherwise there would be no need to write the two "$:$" and give this operation a special name. What your are doing is applying the ordinary commutator relations. Therefore

$$ \hat{f}_2\hat{f}_1^\dagger\hat{f}_2^\dagger=-\hat{f}_1^\dagger\hat{f}_2\hat{f}_2^\dagger=\hat{f}_1^\dagger(1-\hat{f}_2^\dagger\hat{f}_2)$$ is correct, but
$$  :\hat{f}_2\hat{f}_1^\dagger\hat{f}_2^\dagger: \equiv \hat{f}_1^\dagger\hat{f}_2^\dagger\hat{f}_2$$

Comment: How can I understand the minus sign that emerges at the last identity (in the answer from wikipedia)?

Comment: Fermion fields do anticommute: $\{ \hat{f}_1^\dagger , \hat{f}_2^\dagger \} = \hat{f}_1^\dagger  \hat{f}_2^\dagger  + \hat{f}_2^\dagger  \hat{f}_1^\dagger = 0 \rightarrow \hat{f}_1^\dagger  \hat{f}_2^\dagger = - \hat{f}_2^\dagger  \hat{f}_1^\dagger  $